# Dynamicaly update field created with wp_editor()

Tags: jquery, tinymce, wp-editor

I'm trying to get value of hidden `textarea` created by `wp_editor()` or check if anything is typed it, but the problem is that the value is updated on submit, not dynamically. What I need is to validate with jQuery whether the field is filled in or not.

My field:

```
$settings = array(
                            'editor_height' => 300,
                            'media_buttons' => false,
                            'teeny'         => false,
                            'quicktags'     => false
                        );
wp_editor( $post->post_content ,'my_content', $settings);
```

The only idea that I get is:

```
var name = $('iframe#st_content_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce p').length;
```

and then count paragraphs, but this solution seems to me a bit silly. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Check if TinyMCE is active
    if (typeof tinyMCE != "undefined") {
        $('form').on('click', function () {

            if (tinyMCE.activeEditor != null){
            var editorContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
            $('#get_content').val(editorContent).change();

            if ((editorContent === '' || editorContent === null)) {
                $('#get_content').val(editorContent).change();

            }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) you also have

`textLength` property you can call.

Comment: No it's not an issue. The point is that the text field is not updated dynamically, so it would take value of empty field. I've solved it already, but thank you! :)

Comment: Great wrapper, @Rafal